# Writing custom url model field in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating one model called Profile in which i have to add a url field for telegram profile. It takes username as input, but in output it should look like this: [https://t.me/{username}](https://t.me/%7Busername%7D).
How I can create custom model field for this problem. Thanks by the way

My expectation is that, you only enter username, but in output it comes with prefix https://t.me/ and full url path will be [https://t.me/{username}](https://t.me/%7Busername%7D)

Answer (score 2):

Create a property function in your profile model.

```py
@property
def get_telegram_link(self):
    return f"https://t.me/{self.telegram_username}"
```

When accessing the model link on your template or code use:

```py
profile_instance.get_telegram_link()
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function under your model and use it in the template:

```
def get_tg_link(self):
    return f"https://t.me/{self.telegram_username}"
```

or override save function under your model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.telegram_profile = f"https://t.me/{self.tg_username}"
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: enes islam, Laban thanks for help.